# Configuration Issue during spring upgrade

Tags: spring

Below is the issue i am facing during the spring upgrade.I feel the issue is with the doctype.Please suggest

```
   Bean 'cdqiPerformanceMonitor'; nested exception is
  org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
  Configuration problem: Old 1.x 'singleton' attribute in use - upgrade to
 'scope' declaration
  Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-
  INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

Below is the application context xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"     "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">    
<beans>    
   <bean id="cdqiPerformanceMonitor"        
   class="com.tms.cdqi.framework.aop.interceptor.CDQIPerformanceMonitorInterceptor"         />
<bean  id="cdqiApplicationContextFactory"class="com.tms.cdqi.framework.context.CDQIApplicationContextFactoryImpl" />  
<bean  id="commandInvoker"class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean"  
lazy-init="true">  
<property name="jndiName">  
<value>ejb/CommandInvokerLocal</value>  
</property>
<property name="businessInterface">
<value>  
com.tms.cdqi.application.command.invoker.CommandInvoker  
</value>  
</property>  
</bean>  
</beans>
```

Below is the stack trace

```
    listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   failed:
   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
 Configuration problem: Unexpected failure during bean definition parsing
  Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-
  INF/applicationContext.xml]
  Bean 'cdqiPerformanceMonitor'; nested exception is 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
  Configuration problem: Old 1.x 'singleton' attribute in use - upgrade to
 'scope' declaration
 Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-
  INF/applicationContext.xml]
```

Comment: Add content of `applicationContext.xml` please.

Comment: @Jens added the content of xml

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct file? Try to clean and rebuild you project.

Comment: Which version of spring do you upgrade to?

Comment: @Jens its spring 4.1.1 version

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

See [SPR-12167](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12167). Spring no longer accepts `singleton="true"`, so you must use `scope="singleton"` instead.